# How to create instances for phantom types returning phantom type?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, phantom-types

Let's have the following data types:

```
data Foo1 a = Foo1
data Foo2 a = Foo2 (Foo3 a)
data Foo3 a = C1 (Foo1 a) | C2 Int
```

And now we want to be able to get a Foo3 from a Foo1 or an Int.
A solution could be to use a type class:

```
class ToFoo3 a where
    toFoo3 :: a -> Foo3 b -- Here start the problems with this phantom type b...

instance ToFoo3 (Foo1 b) where
    toFoo3 foo1 = C1 foo1

instance ToFoo3 Int where
    toFoo3 int = C2 int
```

And here the compiler complains (rightly!) that it cannot match b with b1 because the "b" of Foo3 in the class definition is not the same as the one of Foo1 in the instance.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I tried to solve it using multi-parameter type classes and functional dependency. However, I get stuck with the Int instance because it has no phantom type and thus the second parameter of the type class is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries and fails, I finally come with a satisfactory answer!
The trick is to use functional dependencies together with a type synonym for the Int type.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses  #-}

data Foo1 a = Foo1
data Foo2 a = Foo2 (Foo3 a)
data Foo3 a = C1 (Foo1 a) | C2 (PhInt a)
data Foo4 = Foo4
type PhInt a = Int -- We use now a PhInt type instead of a type.

class ToFoo3 a b | a -> b where
    toFoo3 :: a -> b

instance ToFoo3 (Foo1 a) (Foo3 a) where
    toFoo3 foo1 = C1 foo1

-- The PhInt type allows us to specify that Foo3 must be generic as is
-- PhInt a.
instance ToFoo3 (PhInt a) (Foo3 a) where
    toFoo3 int = C2 int

test1 = toFoo3 Foo1
test2 = toFoo3 (3::Int)
test3 = toFoo3 (Foo1 :: Foo1 Foo4)

{-
This trick allows us to write a function which can take benefit of the
type class. The important point is that if you would try to do this
without having the "PhInt a" type instead of "Int", when using an integer
you would get as final result a value of type Foo3 Int.
-}
coerce :: ToFoo3 a (Foo3 b) => a -> (Foo3 b, String)
coerce a = (toFoo3 a, "hello")
```

Note: all those complications are here because the instance must convert a "non-phantom" type Int to a phantom type. If we were dealing with phantom types only, we could do something much simpler such as:

```
class ToFoo3 a (Foo3 b) where
    toFoo3 :: a b -> Foo3 b

instance ToFoo3 Foo1 Foo3 where
...
```

Comment: This definitely works, but I've absolutely no clue if this is by chance or if there are some good reasons. So if you have any light to put on this, be welcome!

Answer (score 6):

A multiparameter typeclass *without* a functional dependency compiles for me:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

data Foo1 a = Foo1
data Foo2 a = Foo2 (Foo3 a)
data Foo3 a = C1 (Foo1 a) | C2 Int

class ToFoo3 a b where
    toFoo3 :: a -> Foo3 b

instance ToFoo3 (Foo1 b) b where
    toFoo3 foo1 = C1 foo1

instance ToFoo3 Int b where
    toFoo3 int = C2 int
```

The way I understand it, you cannot have a functional dependency in either direction, since an `Int` needs to be able to convert to any `Foo3 a` type, and `Foo1 a` *also* needs to be able to convert to the same `Foo3 a` type.

Of course this means you cannot expect any of the argument or result type of `toFoo3` to help with infering the other, so you might sometimes need an annoying amount of type annotations to use this, but other than that this should work.

EDIT: I am assuming you *don't* want to be able to convert from `Foo1 a` to `Foo3 b` with `a` and `b` different.  If I am wrong about that, then your OP code with a single-parameter class should work if you change one instance to

```
instance ToFoo3 (Foo1 b) where
    toFoo3 Foo1 = C1 Foo1
```

Comment: As you're pointing out, this solution involves annoying hints to the compiler when using the toFoo3 function: especially if you keep the phantom type of "Foo1 a" generic. So, concretely you cannot write: test = toFoo3 Foo1.

Answer (score 5):

Woah, the other two approaches are complicated.

The easy solution is to remember that these are *phantom* types and you can rebuild them as you see fit. So for example if you have `data Phantom x y = Phantom x` there exists a function `cast (Phantom x) = Phantom x` of type `cast :: Phantom x y -> Phantom x z` which makes the phantom type generic again. The approach is:

1. Deconstruct the object into its non-phantom arguments.
2. Reconstruct the object.
3. Profit.

In this case the **entire solution** is as simple as:

```
instance ToFoo3 (Foo1 b) where
    toFoo3 _ = C1 Foo1
```

Similarly for `Foo2` and `Foo3`, which are the next logical steps:

```
instance ToFoo3 (Foo3 a) where
    toFoo3 (C1 x) = C1 Foo1
    toFoo3 (C2 i) = C2 i

instance ToFoo3 (Foo2 a) where
    toFoo3 (Foo2 x) = toFoo3 x
```

Comment: So easy that I even didn't think of... very elegant solution. The only incovenient I can see is that in case of complex data type, a lot of classes and instances are needed (for example, if Int would be used for different types part of a main type). But the very strong aspects are that you don't need any very special extensions and it keeps the code simple!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you want,
but you can get the compiler to accept something like what you tried 
using [type families](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Type_families):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Stackoverflow where

data Foo1 a = Foo1
data Foo2 a = Foo2 (Foo3 a)
data Foo3 a = C1 (Foo1 a) | C2 Int

class ToFoo3 a where
    type T a :: *
    toFoo3 :: a -> Foo3 (T a)

instance ToFoo3 (Foo1 b) where
    type T (Foo1 b) = b
    toFoo3 foo1 = C1 foo1

instance ToFoo3 Int where
    type T Int = Int
    toFoo3 int = C2 int
```

if you want to get *generic* `Foo3` from integers you can add yet another newtype/`ToFoo3`-instance:

```
newtype AInt a = AInt Int

instance ToFoo3 (AInt a) where
  type T (AInt a) = a
  toFoo3 (AInt int) = C2 int
```

here is a simple test:

```
λ> :t toFoo3 (AInt 5) :: Foo3 Char
toFoo3 (AInt 5) :: Foo3 Char :: Foo3 Char
```

in case you are curious - a error using `Int` instead would look like this:

```
λ> :t toFoo3 (5 :: Int) :: Foo3 Char

<interactive>:1:1:
    Couldn't match type `Int' with `Char'
    Expected type: Foo3 Char
      Actual type: Foo3 (T Int)
    In the expression: toFoo3 (5 :: Int) :: Foo3 Char
```

Comment: I suspect this is not what is wanted since it cannot convert an `Int` to an arbitrary `Foo3 a`, even though all `Foo3 a` have the `C2` constructor.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen probably true - did not think on this - maybe I can *rescue* this with some more hacks - you already gave a solution using multi-param type-classes ;)

Comment: Thank you for the hacks and the edit! This works indeed very fine. Then, it is not always easy to work with since the you may see in some cases the "T" type appearing in function signatures. However, it present the big advantage to limit the amount of code for complex types!

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question, because I've found a recent solution available from GHC 7.8.1 which is the use of the function coerce from the class Coercible.

It presents the following advantages:

1. it is much less code to write;
2. it doesn't imply any additional types in the type signature;
3. it is "safe" (by opposition to unsafeCoerce which could also be a solution in that case);
4. it has zero run-time costs.

The documentation is available here:
https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Coercible

More details can be found in the publication:
http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~eir/papers/2014/coercible/coercible.pdf

Note that the coercion of phantom types is something which is explicitly addressed by coerce (see paragraph 2.2. of the publication).

In the present case it just requires one call to the coerce function and that's it!

```
-- We need to import Data.Coerce (no extensions are required).
import Data.Coerce

data Foo1 a = Foo1
data Foo2 a = Foo2 (Foo3 a)
data Foo3 a = C1 (Foo1 a) | C2 Int

class ToFoo3 a where
    toFoo3 :: a -> Foo3 b

{-|
We just need to apply the coerce function to the returned value.
Note: we could simplify this equation by adopting point free style:
> toFoo3 = coerce.C1
-}
instance ToFoo3 (Foo1 b) where
    toFoo3 foo1 = coerce $ C1 foo1

instance ToFoo3 Int where
    toFoo3 int = C2 int
```

We can now run some tests (which would not compile with the code displayed in the question):

```
test1 = toFoo3 Foo1
test2 = toFoo3 (3::Int)
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the type of a value processed by the function toFoo3 will become generic again in any cases. So, if you would have a type data Foo4 = Foo4 the following equation test3 = toFoo3 (Foo1 :: Foo1 Foo4) would have type Foo3 a. This maybe acceptable in some cases, but most of the time, if you're using phantom type, you want the non-generic types to stay so.